# Is it true that if $f(x)$ is continuous, given $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - cf(y)| < \epsilon$ for any arbitrary $c>0$?

Tags: calculus

Is it true that if $f(x)$ is continuous, given $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - cf(y)| < \epsilon$ for any arbitrary $c>0$?

Does $\delta = \epsilon/c$ work? I don't know how to properly use that fact though.

Comment: What is y ? How does this depend on delta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. Choose for example $f(x)=1$ and $c=2$.